# triggering a Get request with document.body.appendChild()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

We can exchange strings between our express server and a client website (even cross domain) with this code (works perfectly) :

app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var fs=require('fs');
var stringforfirefox = 'hi buddy!'


app.get('/getJSONPResponse', function(req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
    res.end("__parseJSONPResponse(" + JSON.stringify( stringforfirefox) + ");");
});
app.listen(8001)
```

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        function __parseJSONPResponse(data) {    alert(data); }

        document.onkeypress = function keypressed(e){

            if (e.keyCode == 112) {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = 'http://localhost:8001/getJSONPResponse';
                document.body.appendChild(script); // triggers a GET request   ??????

            }



        }
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

We use document.createElement() and  document.body.appendChild() to trigger a Get request as the highest voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596885/cross-domain-jquery-getjson-from-a-node-js-using-express-server-does-not-work#_=_) suggested.
Our question: is it fine to create a new Element with evey request, because we plan to make a lot of requests with this. Could that cause any problems. Or should we clear such an Element after we received the response?